# ColorWithPatternImage and constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a image I need to tile as a background for a UIView:

```
UIView *buttonView = [UIView new];
[buttonView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[buttonView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[buttonBar(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(buttonView)]];
[buttonView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomBar-bg-100.png"]]];
```

The image is 200x200 but I need it to be 100. If I add the image as:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithName:@"bottomBar-bg-100.png"]
```

It will be compress to 100. But when I use the `colorWithPatternImage:` method, it doesn't compress the 200 tall image to be 100 tall.

Is there some goofyness going on with `colorWithPatternImage:` and using constraints, or is that just how the `colorWithPatternImage:` works?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`? This is the best way to turn an image into something that you can stretch or tile into an available size.

Comment: No I don't. Thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: I've written a book that teaches you about it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_uiimage_and_uiimageview